# Modifying jarfile at runtime

Tags: java

I have a question about java. Is it possible to load, get a class and a method within that class, modify the method, recompile the jarfile and overwrite it, all within a java program?

Example:
a.jar has one class, with the static void main() method, that just prints "world"

My goal is it to load a.jar's main class, get the static void main() method, and add another call to print "hello" at the top, then save it to disk again. So now if i run a.jar, it says "world", then I run my program, it saves the jarfile, then I run a.jar again and it says "hello", then "world".

Is something like this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: That seems rather complicated for something that could be solved without changing your java code and JAR content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's ASM library to do it.. I have tested this myself and it works just fine.

For newer versions of `Java > 8`, you have to `export` `jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm` to the current module.. OR if you prefer not to use internal classes, you can download `objectweb.asm`, add it as a dependency and use it the exact same way as below..

Code:

```
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.FieldNode;
import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main cls = new Main();

        //Add a new field to the class called "Main".
        //This field will be called "key" and will have a value of "SomeValue".

        if (cls.getSelfValue("key") == null) {
            System.out.println(cls.modifySelf("key", "SomeValue")); //Prints true upon success.
            System.out.println(cls.getSelfValue("key")); //Prints "SomeValue".
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Key field already exists with a value of: " + cls.getSelfValue("key"));
        }
    }

    //Load the byte-code for the current class.
    private ClassNode getSelf() {
        try {
            ClassNode node = new ClassNode();
            ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            reader.accept(node, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
            return node;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Save the byte-code for the current class.
    private boolean setSelf(ClassNode node) {
        try {
            //Create a class writer. use a ClassCheckAdapter on it to make sure we aren't making any mistakes! The adapter checks whether or not our byte-code makes sense.
            ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
            node.accept(new CheckClassAdapter(writer, false));

            //Save the byte-code for the current class.
            DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(this.getClass().getSimpleName().replace('.', '/') + ".class").getPath())));
            stream.write(writer.toByteArray());
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Add a new field of type "String" to the current class. Give it a name and a value.
    private boolean modifySelf(String name, String value) {
        ClassNode node = this.getSelf(); //Load the byte-code for the current class.
        node.fields.add(new FieldNode(Opcodes.ASM4, name, "Ljava/lang/String;", null, value)); //Add a new field to the class.
        return setSelf(node);
    }

    //Get the field with the specified name from the current class. Return its value.
    private String getSelfValue(String name) {
        ClassNode node = this.getSelf(); //Load the byte-code for the current class.
        for (FieldNode f : node.fields) {
            if (f.name.equals(name) && f.desc.equals("Ljava/lang/String;")) {
                return (String)f.value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code adds a field. To `modify` the `main` method, you can do:

```
for (MethodNode method : mainClassNode.methods) {
    if (method.name.equals("main") && method.desc.equals("()V")) {
        method.instructions.clear();

        method.instructions.add(new LdcInsnNode("Hello"));
        method.instructions.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ASTORE, 0));
        method.instructions.add(new TypeInsnNode(Opcodes.NEW, "java/lang/StringBuilder"));
        method.instructions.add(new InsnNode(Opcodes.DUP));
        method.instructions.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "<init>", "()V", false));
        method.instructions.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0));
        method.instructions.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false));
        method.instructions.add(new LdcInsnNode(" - World"));
        method.instructions.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;", false));
        method.instructions.add(new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/StringBuilder", "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false));

        method.instructions.add(new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ASTORE, 0));

        //Add more instructions to actually call `System.out.println` on `ALOAD_0` (aka stack variable 0.. aka our `StringBuilder.toString()`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution uses internal classes of the JDK that are subject to change without warning, so this might not work in future versions of Java. You're not supposed to use the internal classes of the JDK.

Comment: You can use this in a more future-proof way by using [instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to define a `ClassFileTransformer` and importing ASM as a separate dependency..